# How to apply for job outside my qualification?

Tags: job-search, job-change, job-acceptance, job-satisfaction

I have worked in one kind of job, but realized that it is not the right job for me.I decided to apply for both new kind of jobs and the original type of job, but it seems I am stuck.

For current type of job, I am not good enough. But on the other side, when I apply for new kind of job, I am rejected, probably because I do not have the right job experience/school.

Of course I sent both CV and cover letter, where I explained why I could be suitable for that job.

What should I do now?

Comment: What stops you from *getting* that certification/school/diploma?

Comment: @nvoigt There is no problem with school.

Comment: Then it seems getting that right certificate/school is the way to go?

Answer (score 4):

> I have worked in one kind of job, but realized that it is not the right job for me.I decided to apply for both new kind of jobs and the original type of job, but it seems I am stuck.

Don't despair - you aren't the only person who got into a job/career and found it wasn't for them!

> For current type of job, I am not good enough. But on the other side, when I apply for new kind of job, I am rejected, probably because I do not have the right job experience/school.

You're probably on the money there - in general terms having school + experience is your best bet, having experience (but no school) probably second and finally having just the school qualifications.

That's not to say you *can't* get a role in a new career without any of these - but it's going to be a tough sell unless you're moving from a career where you have some obviously transferable skills, and you'd probably have to start right at the bottom.

If you're applying for roles that explicitly list qualifications (be that academic or experience) that you don't have your chances are going to be extremely, *extremely* slim. If there's no required qualifications - or there are ones you have or equivalents to then you can apply and make your case in the CV and cover letter as you have been doing.

> What should I do now?

If roles in your new desired career are consistently asking for a qualification you don't have then it's time to break out the ol' textbooks and go get that qualification!

Good luck!

Answer (score -5):

There are three possible issues for why you are unemployable for the positions you are applying:

1. You lack some of the skills required
2. You lack the experience
3. You lack the credentials(an education or cert.)

A maximum of one of these can apply to you for you to get the job.

This leaves you with four options if you want to get a job you are unqualified for:

1. Find a job posting where a maximum of one of the issues above applies, and apply
2. Take steps to correct as many of the above issues as possible.
3. Nepotism
4. Kneepads and determination.

Comment: I don't understand all of the down votes.  I'm a pragmatist and I think this advice is valid.